# Can't get .text() to display limited characters

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set a limit of the character a div can display but somehow it never works

To begin with I'm kinda noob in programming so hope you guys keep it simple or atleast explains why and your code.

This is the code i have writen so far

```
        <div class = "text1">
        <p>once upon a time</p>
        </div>
```

the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".text1").text(function(index, text) {
        return text.substr(0, 10);
     });
});
```

But it doesn't limited the characters to 10 but just display the whole text.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AkWM/), but the selector should be `$('.text1 p')`

Comment: because there are multi level text...

Comment: already tried $('.text1 p') but not working either and yes i did include jQuery in my page :S

Comment: Open your console and look for errors

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to trim the white space first:

```
$.trim(text).substr(0, 10);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5xjL8/)**

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP's code is displaying "the whole text" ?

Comment: @adeneo - It never displayed the whole text for me. But without the trim the first characters are all white space.

Comment: It never did for me either, but it does for the OP apparently, so there is something else going on ?

Comment: @adeneo - Guess we'll need the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var short_text = $(".text1 p").text().substr(0, 10);
   $(".text1 p").text(short_text);
});
```

The text will be 'once upon '

Comment: Of course it does, it's exactly the same as the code in the question

Comment: But the question is that it doesn't limit the text to 10 characters? Or am I missing some crucial detail?

Comment: And the code in the most recent version of Firefox just returns: `o`